# JQuery Fast Track for Study

Tags: jquery

What is the fast track for learning JQuery?

What are the good references to refer?

How do I really practice JQuery in ASP.net web applications ?

Answer (score 1):

Play here: http://jsfiddle.net/ (Pick jQuery 1.6.2 in the left side)

Search for things you want to play with in the jQuery docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

The best way to learn is to try things out. jQuery is Javascript, you need to learn it standalone with some HTML that could be generated from an ASP.net page, but you don't need to use it with ASP to learn it.

If you have a lot of experience in Javascript, you can read jQuery's source code too: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js. You need to already have Javascript experience to read it, but if you do then understanding what's going on when you write jQuery code snippets will help you write better code.